# Style particle hair to a fine point?

Tags: particles, hair

I've been hoping to recreate some video game characters hair in a more realistic way, but I ran into an issue where I can recreate the hair collecting to a point, but because of the children it separates apart creating a much looser look.

[image]

Is it possible to make it a finer point? I want the hairs to group together, as well as the children like a stylized mustache that ends in points, or similar to an anime wig in these examples below. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Under `Children > Clumping` set the `Clump` value to something closer to 1, maybe 0.75 or 0.85. You can also mess with the `Shape` or `Clump Curve` options to get a different look